# My endorsement policy does not work correctly?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I have created a fabric network which consists of six organization which contains two peers per each. After successfully starting the network I install and instantiate the fabcar chaincode. This is the command which I used to instantiate the chaincode.

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -n fabcar -l node -v 1.0  -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -C mychannel -P "AND ('Org2MSP.peer','Org1MSP.peer','Org3MSP.peer','Org4MSP.peer','Org5MSP.peer','Org6MSP.peer')"
```

After instantiating successfully I tried to invoke the first transaction and it leaves me this error on the peer.

> 2019-05-13 04:10:33.465 UTC [vscc] Validate -> ERRO 170 VSCC error:
>   stateBasedValidator.Validate failed, err validation of endorsement
>   policy for chaincode fabcar in tx 8:0 failed: signature set did not
>   satisfy policy 2019-05-13 04:10:33.465 UTC [committer.txvalidator]
>   validateTx -> ERRO 171 VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId =
>   bfcc1867bc68dddb7852ae8b819ab404f6239bcd1f0eda6cd4074490bc856a0b
>   returned error: validation of endorsement policy for chaincode fabcar
>   in tx 8:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy

If I replace the AND in the policy with OR, If I replace the policy with  `-p "AND ('Org2MSP.peer')"`.It was worked successfully without leaving the error. I install the chaincode on one peer of each organization and instantiated the network on org2 peer0.

This is my configtx.yaml file.

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"

        # leave this flag set to true.
        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org2MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin','Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"



        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 9051


    - &Org3
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org3MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org3MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin','Org3MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org3.example.com
              Port: 11051


    - &Org4
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org4MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org4MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin', 'Org4MSP.peer', 'Org4MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin','Org4MSP.peer', 'Org4MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org4.example.com
              Port: 13051


    - &Org5
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org5MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org5MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org5MSP.admin', 'Org5MSP.peer', 'Org5MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org5MSP.admin','Org5MSP.peer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org5MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org5.example.com
              Port: 15051

    - &Org6
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org6MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org6MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org6.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org6MSP.admin', 'Org6MSP.peer', 'Org6MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org6MSP.admin','Org6MSP.peer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org6MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org6.example.com
              Port: 17051

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Channel is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running at the v1.3.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers and peers from
        # prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.3 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v1.3.0 or later.
        V1_3: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Orderer is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running at the v1.1.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers from prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.1 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on a channel are at v1.1.0 or later.
        V1_1: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3.
        V1_3: true
        # V1.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.2 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set)
        V1_2: false
        # V1.1 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set).
        V1_1: false

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    SixOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
                    - *Org4
                    - *Org5
                    - *Org6
    SixOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
                - *Org4
                - *Org5
                - *Org6
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: can you post the invoke command you are using?

Comment: `peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["initLedger"]}'`

Comment: @Harshit This is the command I used to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

In the invoke command you are not specifying the `--peerAddresses` and `--tlsRootCertFiles`(if you have enabled tls) of the respective anchor peers to connect to. try adding these feilds:

> **--peerAddresses** **peer0.org1**.example.com:9051 **--tlsRootCertFiles** /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt 
>   **--peerAddresses peer0.org2**.example.com:9051 **--tlsRootCertFiles** /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
>   ... **similarly for org 3..6**

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'
```

you can refer to: [Invoke command](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#invoke)